# Is it neccessary if query runs table will be filled?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If we run any query is it necessary that the table is affected after the query runs. or is there any chance query runs and table doesnot get affected

for eg

```
if($db->query("Insert into table(name) values('myname')")
{
 //do something
}
```

I have wrapped the code in a if statement. It executes if the if query runs. Is there any chance that code inside if statement is executed without inserting the name in database table?

Comment: You mean for that particular query, or for any query in general?

Comment: Depends on your DB library. Generally, a query() call which fails will return false, causing the if() itself to fail.

Comment: @rid in general for insert update & delete

Comment: @MarcB i'm using PDO mysql. So there is a chance that it may fail?

Comment: `$db->query("Insert into table(name) values('myname')"` will always return *something*, and thus evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @Ace, sure, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` could run without affecting the database. For example, maybe there is no such row. In that case, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` will do nothing. Or, maybe a row with a constraint already exist. In that case, `INSERT` will behave in a way in which it will not change the database.

Comment: of course. there's exactly **ONE** way for a query to succeed. and a near infinite number of ways for it to fail. bad db connection, db server crashes, db runs out of space. space-time continuum ruptures and sucks your server into the twilight zone. foreign key violations, primary key violations, constraint violations, blah blah blah

Comment: @Ace, MySQL offers a way of finding out how many rows were affected by the last query. This is exposed through both PDO and the `mysqli_*` interface (and the obsolete `mysql_*` one as well).

Comment: For updates and deletes you have `affected_rows()` and if im correct inserts have `inserted_rows()`

Comment: Since it is technically possible for your server to be sucked into the twilight zone, don't forget to check for a ThatReallySucksException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No... But it depends on what you are trying to do.  One thing PDO supports is Transactions (http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php)

Basically, you can create a transaction, and if it fails, then it won't commit those inserts/updates/deletes to the database.

```
try {  
  $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $dbh->beginTransaction();
  $dbh->exec("insert into staff (id, first, last) values (23, 'Joe', 'Bloggs')");
  $dbh->exec("insert into salarychange (id, amount, changedate) 
      values (23, 50000, NOW())");
  $dbh->commit();

} catch (Exception $e) {
  $dbh->rollBack();
  echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth would you need a situation in which you don't want to run an `UPDATE` statement but use it in an if condition?

So if the `query()` fails, it returns 0, else 1. Period.